# What class does this method (read) come from (open-uri ruby)

Tags: ruby

I read some code like:

```
source = URI.join(uri).read
```

This basically goes to the URI, and stores the source of the webpage in the variable.

I tried this in IRB:

```
URI.join(uri).class
```

and it returned `URI::HTTP`, but, when I tried `URI.join(uri).read.class => String`.

I checked `String` class but there is no `read` method there.

I want to stub this method but am not able to because I don't know where it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-read) is from Ruby's [StringIO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) module, which acts like the normal [IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) class.

[OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) provides [`read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-read) via the [StringIO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) class, which is how it fools us, and our code, into thinking the URL is a device we can read from.

`URI.join(uri).read.class` returns `String` because the page is read from the site pointed to by the URL, and the content is a string. OpenURI overrides the URI class and adds `read` to it. If you try:

```
require 'uri'
URI.join('http://example.com').read
```

without having required OpenURI, you'll get an error because, by itself, URI doesn't know how to `read`.

```
URI.join('http://example.com')
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x0000010292de68 URL:http://example.com>

URI.join('http://example.com').read
NoMethodError: undefined method `read' for #<URI::HTTP:0x0000010218b3b8 URL:http://example.com>
```

Comment: Aah. thanks for that. Makes sense. BTW is there any way I could stub this read to return what I want?

Comment: You want to overwrite OpenURI's `read`? Why? Why not sub-class OpenURI and overwrite it in your sub-class so you don't mess with anything else that might need to use OpenURI.read?

Comment: So, my StubClass should have the name OpenURI? If I do StubClass < OpenURI and then def read #override how will my test know when it gets to the line URI.join().read that read is overridden in another class? Am I missing something here?

Comment: You need to learn how to sub-class and define methods that override existing methods. It's not hard, but its an essential part of programming in Ruby. Look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than stub `URI.read()` (provided by OpenURI as noted in [the Tin Man's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14407293/27358)), consider using a library like [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) that can intercept HTTP requests regardless of the exact mechanism used to make them.